# error makeNodePromisified is not a function when bundling bluebird with webpack

Tags: promise, webpack, bluebird

When I bundle bluebird with webpack and target `node` I'm getting the following error -

```
makeNodePromisified(key, THIS, key, fn, suffix, multiArgs);
                ^

TypeError: makeNodePromisified is not a function
at promisifyAll (...)
at Function.e.24.module.exports.Promise.promisifyAll (...)
```

It appears to be pulling in `./node_modules/bluebird/browser/bluebird.js` which has `__BROWSER__` replaced with `true`.  How do I pull in the non-browser version?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pull bluebird directly from webpack, the source isn't designed to work this way because of optimizations performed.

Instead, include the minfieid result and set an alias to the minified end-result file:

```
externals: {
    "Promise": "Promise"
}
```

In your Webpack configuration file. Alternatively you can ignore it as suggested [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/254#issuecomment-52871639) if you don't need the type feedback (not using TypeScript for instance).